# Windows Server 2016 Update Failure Rollback

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-update

When I attempt to run an update using check for updates or the cumulative offline installer, the update fails and rolls back.

Here's the log from the rollback, not sure how much I should include, so this is just before the start of errors occurring:

> 2023-04-30 13:33:47, Info                  CSI    0000026b Loading CMI
> installer DLL from path:
> C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft-windows-s..ck-mof-onecoreadmin_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.14393.5771_none_8f44d8b389d444af\mofinstall.dll 2023-04-30 13:33:47, Error                 CSI
> 0000026c@2023/4/30:18:33:47.108 (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message
> from AI HRESULT = E_INVALIDARG  [ 'The parameter is incorrect.
>
> ' ] [gle=0x80004005] 2023-04-30 13:33:47, Error                 CSI
> 0000026d@2023/4/30:18:33:47.108 (F) CMIADAPTER: AI failed. HRESULT =
> E_INVALIDARG
> Element:
> '' [gle=0x80004005] 2023-04-30 13:33:47, Error                 CSI
> 0000026e@2023/4/30:18:33:47.108 (F) CMIADAPTER: Exiting with HRESULT
> code = E_INVALIDARG.

Any idea what's going on?

Up to this point, I've tried just about everything. This is a domain controller, so I really don't want to replace it quite yet.

I've run sfc /scannow several times as well as DISM commands. I've removed AV, and I've disabled all unnecessary services. I've tried running the update manually by extracting the cab file from the msu and running it through dism command line. it always rolls back at the same point for the same reason, but I can't make sense of the reason and I'm not finding anything online about this specific line:

2023-04-30 13:33:47, Error                 CSI    0000027a@2023/4/30:18:33:47.685 (F) CMIADAPTER: Inner Error Message from AI HRESULT = E_INVALIDARG
[
'The parameter is incorrect.

'
]